# Не могу правильно составить сложный запрос MySql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-api

Нужно на фронте в админке сайта Wordpress сделать с помощью Google Bar Chart таблицу статистики продаж товаров, сгруппированную по дате и конкретной группе товара.

Вид [примерно такой](https://gyazo.com/7298e77b3220a3a1985d2753e4122024).

Всю информацию нужно брать из базы данных, в которой три таблицы. И у меня не получается правильно составить запрос к базе данных, чтобы в результате после преобразования в JSON я получал двумерный массив вида:
`[['10.11.2015', 10, 30, 45, 50]...[]]`, где первый элемент - уникальная дата, все остальные элементы - количество проданных в эту даты товаров из каждой группы.

Только в таком формате Google Charts API можно передать информацию.

Я пробовал следующий вариант запроса и обработки:

```
global $wpdb;       
  $my_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(orders.o_creationdate, '%d.%m.%Y') AS formated_date, COUNT(products.p_id) as counter
  FROM orders 
  LEFT JOIN products
    ON orders.o_productid = products.p_id
  LEFT JOIN productgroups
    ON products.p_productgroupid = productgroups.pg_id 
  GROUP BY  productgroups.pg_id, formated_date");   
$rows = array();
      $table = array();
      $table['cols'] = array(

        // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
        /* 
            note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format 
            as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage 
            and string will be used for Slice title
        */

        array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

    );

        /* Extract the information from $result */
        foreach($my_result as $r) {


          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart


          $rows[] = array((string)$r->formated_date,  (int)$r->counter );
          $rows[0] = array('Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses');
        }


    // convert data into JSON format

$jsonTable = json_encode($rows);

//echo $jsonTable;
```

Но этот вариант плохо подходит, так как в результате получается двумерный массив вида `[['10.11.15', 10], ['10.11.15', 15]...[]]`, то есть двойная группировка в запросе приводит к тому, что количество товаров определенной группы и дата выводятся как отдельный элемент. А мне нужно, что в одном элементе массива выводилась уникальная дата (первый элемент) и количество проданных товаров по каждой группе

Дамп базы можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fzcdi5b2cdebshb/AAAwTOoGN42c2znIDyflaMyEa/db?dl=0).

Благодарен за любую помощь/совет.

Comment: В запрос надо добавить сортировку по дате (order by formated_date). в цикле обработки надо запоминать в переменной дату которую видели последней и если дата в текущей строке совпадает с запомненной - то добавлять значение в существующий подмассив, а если дата изменилась - то создавать новый подмассив и запоминуть уже эту дату на будущее

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли, простое решение и все работает)